# just started learning shell script, can't solve this problem

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

```bash
foo=username
bar=foo

a=$(eval echo \$$bar) # same as ${!bar}

echo $(eval echo \$${a^^}) # expected val
```

How to get the value of foo through the variable bar，
Same as the above output

I know it wants a variable name not a string here.

```bash
echo $(eval echo \$${${!bar}^^}) # error bad substitution
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: You virtually never need to use `eval`. What value do you expect `a` to receive?

Comment: I wanna to learn more about it through multiple ways！My English is not  good. If I don't speak clearly, please forgive lol……

Comment: just express  a（variable） has the same result as the next line!

Comment: `a=$(eval echo \$$bar)` is a bit odd.  Normally, that would be written `eval "a=\$$bar"`

Comment: ok, i will notice that,but  `a=$(eval echo \$$bar)`  and  `eval "a=\$$bar"` is not equal.

Comment: If you are trying to defer the command substitution, you could do: `eval "a=\$(\$$bar)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you want to start with:

```
foo=username
bar=$foo
```

... where `username` is the literal string, you want to put in the variable, named `foo`, and `$foo` is the value of the variable `foo`, which you want to put in the variable, named `bar`.

If you want to create another variable, let's say `a`, which contains the value of `bar`, you just do:

```
a=$bar
```

Comment: if I want to get  result pass by the second piece of code , what do i do

Comment: @Holger: I've edited my answer in order to answer to your comment. However, I have the impression that you're making things extremely complicated. What, in fact, are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I just want to think deeper， thank you!

Comment: @Holger: in case my answer was useful or correct, please upvote and/or accept it for reference purposes. This is how this site works.

Answer (score 1):

**BASH** The  order  of  expansions is: brace expansion; tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, arithmetic expansion, and command substitution.

Case conversion is part of parameter and variable expansion.  To see the value of the case-converted variable name without assigning another variable you can do:

```
foo=username
echo \$${foo^^}
$USERNAME
echo $(eval echo \$${foo^^})
stark
```

Comment: year ! i just want understand deeply! your have a goog idea.